# wifi connection failed

Tags: wireless, internet

I have ubuntu and windows in my pc and every thing was working well. But yesterday when I was working in ubuntu wifi become disconnected and it (and any other wifi conection) don't connect any more. And in windows i can connect to it easily. Now when I run ubuntu, it trys to connect to wifi automaticaly but it can not every times and say "connection failed" and trys again...
Can some one say me what should i do? remember that I can not use internet to inestall any packages.

And I use this command: lspci knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list

And out put is:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [11ad:0662]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please update your ubuntu and then your windows respectively and try again

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: How can I update ubuntu when I can not connect to internet?

Comment: Run `sudo systemctl restart network-manager`

Comment: I do but nothing happend.

Comment: Now i recive this massage: Sorry, ubuntu 18.04 has experienced an internal error. AND in detals exist: ExecutablePath:/usr/bin/gnome-control-center

Comment: And in title in details: gnome-control-center crashed with SIGSIGV in nm _device_filter_connections()